# Type mismatch error when creating a PivotCache

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a Pivot table on a newsheet using dynamic range, but getting an error that says:

> **Run time error: 13** Type Mismatch

Googled the error and as per my understanding, the code contains data type that is not matched correctly, but I am not able to figure out where is the error:

Using Excel 2016.

```
Sub EEE()

 Dim PrevSheet As Worksheet
 Set PrevSheet = ActiveSheet

 Sheets.Add.Name = "Pivottable"
 PrevSheet.Select

 ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
                                  SourceData:=ActiveSheet.UsedRange, _
                                  Version:=xlPivotTableVersion15).CreatePivotTable _
                                  TableDestination:="Pivottable!R3C1", _
                                  TableName:="PivotTable1", _
                                  DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion15

 Sheets("Pivottable").Select
 Cells(3, 1).Select

 With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Faculty")
 .Orientation = xlRowField
 .Position = 1
 End With

 With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("NPS")
 .Orientation = xlColumnField
 .Position = 1
 End With        
End Sub
```

**Modified Code - Working**

```
Sub EEE()

  Dim rng     As Range
  Dim pc      As PivotCache
  Dim pt      As PivotTable
  Dim ws      As Worksheet

   Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion

   Set pc = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabaseSourceData:=rng.Address)
   Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
   ws.Name = "NewSheet"
   Set pt = pc.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=Range("A3"),TableName:="pvttbl")

  With pt
     .PivotFields("Faculty").Orientation = xlRowField

      ActiveSheet.PivotTables("pvttbl").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTable "pvttbl").PivotFields("NPS"), "Count of NPS", xlCount

     .PivotFields("NPS").Orientation = xlColumnField
  End With
End Sub
```

Comment: which line does the error occur on? Step through code with F8 and see which line is highlighted when error hits.

Comment: Also avoid Activesheet where possible and refer  to sheet by its name and the worksheets collection. And avoid using Select where possible and use With statement

Comment: Entire "ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create...."  is highlighted

Comment: I would have made the same points as Jeffrey has just pointed out and also that if you are using 2016 you should be able to put DefaultVersion:=6

Comment: Note that bits of your code are redundant. Check my answer below to see the bits you can skip. No need to select things, don't need to set .Position, and can break the creation of the PivotCache and the creation of the PivotTable down into two separate events for simplicity.

Comment: Note that I have amended my code just now to make it simpler still, so make sure you grab the latest version.

Comment: Included in the modified code. Could not modify the data field .AddDataField

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't say what line is giving the error. But there's a couple of possible culprits. 
The line `SourceData:=ActiveSheet.UsedRange` says "Hey, go make the PivotTable out of *everything* you find on the active sheet". Not a good idea. Use the exact range where the data is. Either select a cell where there block of data is and use the CurrentRegion e.g.

```
SourceData:= Activesheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
```

...or even better, turn that SourceData into an Excel Table aka ListObject earlier in the code, and reference that ListObject:

```
SourceData:= "Table1"
```

Your code will also fail if you try to run it more than once and you haven't deleted the sheet called "PivotTable" that it created last time.

Here's how I would code this up:

```
Option Explicit

Sub EEE()

Dim rng     As Range
Dim pc      As PivotCache
Dim pt      As PivotTable
Dim pf      As PivotField
Dim ws      As Worksheet

Set rng = Range("A1").CurrentRegion '<- Change to the address of the top left cell in your data.

Set pc = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=rng.Address)
Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
Set pt = pc.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=Range("A1"))

With pt
    .PivotFields("Faculty").Orientation = xlRowField
    .PivotFields("NPS").Orientation = xlColumnField
End With


End Sub
```

Comment: Adding [.CurrentRegion] solved my issue.